# Yoast primary category query modification

Tags: wp-query, query, pagination, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a problem with Yoast and displaying my *primary category* alongside rest of the posts from that category.

Let's say I have 4 posts, all of them are `lorem` category and one post has set `lorem` as *primary category*. Currently the `lorem` category page (`/category/lorem`) displays only the three posts that aren't set as primary of its category.

I have in my `category.php` a simply WP query:

```
<?php $current_category = single_cat_title('', false); ?>

<?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

  $args = array(
    'category_name' => $current_category,
    'paged' => $paged
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
  /* do stuff */
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
```

How can I modify the current WP query to also include the *primary category* alongside with pagination?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will fix it, but maybe try using the current category slug for the `$current_category` variable, instead of `single_cat_title()`, like so:

```
   $term = get_queried_object();
   $current_category = $term->slug;
```

This might help because the `category_name` parameter in [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), despite its name, should be the term **slug**. `single_cat_title(`) returns the displayed category title, not slug.

Comment: Nice, seems to work. Tnx! Will this also work with pagination?

Comment: Don't know why it wouldn't work with pagination @Vucko - let us know if it doesn't. :)